# @Transactional not work

Tags: spring, hibernate

i config hibernate with spring the blow config and class fiels:
`model`:
`package com.model`;

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    public Person(Long id, String name, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static long getSerialVersionUID() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

and repository class file:

```
package com.dao.impl;

import com.dao.IPersonRepository;
import com.model.Person;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

/**
 * Created by ramezanimatin on 8/18/2015.
 */
@Repository
public class PersonRepository implements IPersonRepository {
    public PersonRepository() {
    }

    private Session getSession() {
        try {
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            return sessionFactory.openSession();
        }
    }
    @Autowired(required = true)
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void insertPerson(Person person) {
        Session s = getSession();
        s.save(person);
    }
}
```

and config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:oracle-hibernate.properties"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com"/>


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="1234"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.model"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"
                          proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

`pom`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>test</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

when the insertPerson method of PersonRepository is call,no Data is inserted into dataBase
in other world the @Transactional not work

Comment: Is it possible your transaction is read only? Please post the calling code or a detailed log output.

Comment: in Controller I create a Perosn Object and send to Service and it send to Repository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you creating Person while setting the id? If so, it might be the problem, as hibernate thinks the object already exists and tries to update instead of insert. Try using a sequence and let hibernate set the id.